# Is there a plugin for Eclipse that immediately evaluates a highlighted expression?

Tags: eclipse, debugging, netbeans, ide

A colleague of mine uses Netbeans, and I noticed a tremendously useful feature it has in debug mode: it immediately shows what a highlighted expression evaluates to in a tooltip. I'm not sure whether this is a standard feature in Netbeans, but I would definitely find it useful in Eclipse as well.

Does anyone know a plugin or a similar way of using this in Eclipse?

EDIT:
Eclipse provides tooltips for single variable evaluation and expressions evaluation in the expressions view. This is not what I need. In Netbeans, you can highlight an *expression* (possibly containing more than one variable) and it gets evaluated in a tooltip.

Answer (score 2):

In Eclipse debug mode you can add needed expression to Expression view and check its value or you can hover mouse over variables and check theirs values

Comment: wow, I didn't know about dragging, still, not was I was looking for.

Comment: Did you read question? Did you tried this in Netbeans? In Netbeans you select the expression in editor and see the evaluated value in popup!

Answer (score 0):

In Eclipse, when you're running your program in the debugger, you should be able to add a Watcher for a variable, or just simply evaluate an expression (I believe) in the Watcher tab.  Sorry, I don't actually use Eclipse full-time, this is just from memory as I have used it in the past...

Answer (score 0):

Three years later (don't know if it was before) you can `Inspect` the selected expression.
Select it, right click and choose Inspect, or press Ctrl+Shift+I (personally I changed that shortcut to one more reachable F12).